# Can't connect screen via adapter on ubuntu 17.10 because of grafics card driver

Tags: drivers, graphics

**Here is my problem:**
I have Ubuntu 17.10 on my Laptop and I'd like to connect two separate screens. On my dock I have only one VGA connection so for the other screen I have to use an adapter. The screen with the direct VGA connection is working just fine, but on the other screen I can only see my mouse.

I think that the graphics card driver is causing troubles, but I don't know what.

This is the result for `lspci -v | grep VGA -A 1` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
--
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
```

On the "Details" page of my settings it says my graphics is **Intel Haswell Mobile**.

Does anyone know what graphics card driver I have to install so that I can use my second screen too? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this same problem.

The only solution I've found was to setup manually */etc/X11/xorg.conf*

and then setup Monitors with xrandr.

Comment: Can you please clarify on how they should configure the said file? What are the desired effects. ? Any links to help them on configuring?